# Where to add new files to application hosted on OpenShift?

Tags: git, openshift

Where do I place files within the git clone of a new OpenShift application in order to deploy the changes?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what type of application you created.  There should be existing files already that you can see for the demo application that was created, that should give you a pretty good idea of where to put them, if you update your question to include what cartridges you used, I can give you a more detailed answer.

EDIT:

Since you are using JBoss AS7, then you should do a git clone of your newly created application.  You will see a file structure already laid out for you that looks like this (https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/tree/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossas/versions/7/template).  Your source code goes into the src directory, and your dependencies go into the pom.xml file.  You might want to read up some on maven based projects if you are not familiar with how they work.  Then your source code will get built and deployed when you do a git push.

Comment: I used JBoss Application Server 7.

Comment: I expanded on my answer for JBoss AS7 above

Comment: I started a Tomcat application and replaced the main folder located within the src folder with my java application package, then I deployed the app. Is openshift now running the Java application?

Comment: Did you do a git commit & git push?  If you visit your application url, is it showing your application?